# Удаление элементов из хэш таблицы

Tags: python

Всем здравствуйте!
Делаю несложную хэш таблицу. Для этого написал вот такой класс:

```py
class HashTable:
    size = 20

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        try:
            while self.data[h]:
                if self.data[h] and self.data[h]["key"] == key:
                    return self.data[h]
                h = self.get_rehash(h)
        except IndexError:
            return

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        if self.data[h] is None:
            self.data[h] = {"key": key, "value": value}
            return

        next_h = self.get_rehash(h)
        try:
            while self.data[next_h] is not None:
                if self.data[next_h]["key"] == key:
                    self.data[next_h]["key"] = value
                    break
                next_h = self.get_rehash(next_h)
        except IndexError:
            raise
        self.data[next_h] = {"key": key, "value": value}

    def get_hash(self, name):
        return len(name) % self.size

    def get_rehash(self, oldhash):
        return oldhash + 1
```

Исходные данные для формирования хэш таблицы такие:

```
d = {'Водоросли': 280,
 'Картофель': 260,
 'Лук-порей': 59,
 'Манго': 291,
 'Орехи грецкие': 266,
 'Салями': 225,
 'Специи': 283,
 'Сыр сливочный': 152,
 'Творог': 215,
 'Тофу': 142,
 'Хек': 248,
 'Чай черный': 118,
 'Чернила каракатицы': 95,
 'Шампиньоны': 101,
 'Финик': 104}

table = HashTable()
for k, v in d.items():
    table[k] = v

print(table.data)
```

Для удаления элемента из хэш таблицы написал такую функцию в классе

```
def delete(self, key):
    h = self.get_hash(key)
    if self.data[h]["key"] == key:
        self.data[h] = None
        return

    h_next = self.get_rehash(h)
    try:
        while self.data[h_next] is not None:
            if self.data[h_next]["key"] == key:
                self.data[h_next] = None
                break
            h_next = self.get_rehash(h_next)
    except IndexError:
        raise
    self.data[h_next] = None
```

Но работает она не совсем правильно. Если я, например, удаляю элемент по ключу "Водоросли", то потом не могу найти "Картофель" и "Лук-порей", т.к. у них одинаковый хэш (9). Помогите сделать корректное удаление.

Спасибо!

Comment: `у них одинаковый хэш (9)` сделайте нормальный хэш, например от sha1

Comment: @gil9red, как будто хорошая хеш-функция избавляет от необходимости обработки коллизий)

Answer (score 1):

По идее нужно при удалении помечать место в хеш-таблице специальным маркером, который при дальнейшем поиске нужно пропускать.

Вот, попытался что-то изобразить с минимумом изменений:

```
class HashTable:
    class Deleted:
        pass
    size = 20

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        try:
            while self.data[h]:
                while isinstance(self.data[h], HashTable.Deleted): # skip deleted
                    h = self.get_rehash(h)
                if self.data[h] and self.data[h]["key"] == key:
                    return self.data[h]
                h = self.get_rehash(h)
        except IndexError:
            return

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        h = self.get_hash(key)

        try:
            while self.data[h] is not None:
                if self.data[h]["key"] == key:
                    self.data[h]["key"] = value
                    return
                h = self.get_rehash(h)
        except IndexError:
            raise
        self.data[h] = {"key": key, "value": value}

    def get_hash(self, name):
        return len(name) % self.size

    def get_rehash(self, oldhash):
        return oldhash + 1

    def delete(self, key):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        if self.data[h] and self.data[h]["key"] == key:
            self.data[h] = HashTable.Deleted()
            return

        h_next = self.get_rehash(h)
        try:
            while self.data[h_next] is not None:
                while isinstance(self.data[h_next], HashTable.Deleted): # skip deleted
                    h_next = self.get_rehash(h_next)

                if self.data[h_next]["key"] == key:
                    self.data[h_next] = HashTable.Deleted()
                    break
                h_next = self.get_rehash(h_next)
        except IndexError:
            raise
        self.data[h_next] = None

d = {'Водоросли': 280,
 'Картофель': 260,
 'Лук-порей': 59,
 'Манго': 291,
 'Орехи грецкие': 266,
 'Салями': 225,
 'Специи': 283,
 'Сыр сливочный': 152,
 'Творог': 215,
 'Тофу': 142,
 'Хек': 248,
 'Чай черный': 118,
 'Чернила каракатицы': 95,
 'Шампиньоны': 101,
 'Финик': 104}

table = HashTable()
for k, v in d.items():
    table[k] = v

print(*table.data,'\n', sep='\n')

table.delete('Водоросли')
print(*table.data,'\n', sep='\n')

print(table['Картофель'])
```

Периодически необходимо запускать ремаппинг, с очисткой удалённых слотов и переразмещением элементов по пересчитанным в связи с этим «адресам»

Также `rehash+=1` недостаточно, нужно замыкать пространство индексов в кольцо, останавливаясь после полного прохода.

Размер хранилища/область определения хеш-функции слишком малы по сравнению с количеством элементов, которые вы пытаетесь в нём хранить.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при удалении элемента другие элементы сдвигались (если это нужно)? Например, если я удаляю "Водоросли", "Картофель" и "Лук-порей" сдвигаются на один индекс влево и я б получил

Comment: Сдвиг при каждом удалении подразумевает перерасчёт многих хешей. Если вы готовы пожертвовать производительностью delete, можно и так.

Comment: Код пишу в академических целях, поэтому хотел бы сделать со смещением элементов (такое требование). Помогите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен

Comment: Хм, прошу прощения, но на текущий вопрос, я считаю, вами ответ получен. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, не стесняйтесь, [задавайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) его, указав необходимые подробности.

Comment: Ну, или вы можете добавить подробности в текущий вопрос и подождать ответов от других участников. Мой ответ тогда станет не вполне корректным)

Comment: Предложенный ответ очень хороший, но, при всем уважении к автору, это немного не то, что мне нужно. Попробую уточнить свою потребность. Я бы хотел, чтобы после удаления элемента другие сдвигались (если правильно понял, то должен происходить перерасчет хэшей). Например, удаляем 'Орехи грецкие'. Соответственно, для 'Сыр сливочный', 'Шампиньоны' и 'Финик' должен пересчитаться хэш и они должны подняться на индекс выше. Иначе последующий поиск будет работать некорректно. Вот это-то и вызывает основное затруднение. Не знаю, как это реализовать (до этого с хэш таблицами сталкиваться не приходилось)